# How to install psensor?

Tags: software-installation

How can I install `psensor` and use it my Ubuntu mate? I think my laptop has an overheating problem.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install psensor`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

type this in terminal.

```
sudo apt-get install psensor
```